# Parse XML document with elements like <g:id> using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>SSS Product Feed</title>
    <link>https://en-ae.sssports.com/</link>
    <description><![CDATA[The largest sports ]]></description>
    <item>
      <g:id>NIKE315122-001</g:id>
      <g:title><![CDATA[Nike Air Force 1 Low 07 Shoe]]></g:title> 
      <g:sport>Lifestyle</g:sport>
    </item>
    <item>
      <g:id>NIKE315122-002</g:id>
      <g:title><![CDATA[Nike Air Force 1 Low 07 Shoe]]></g:title> 
      <g:sport>Lifestyle</g:sport>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

this is sample xml file which i want to read and parse....

i have java classes like this....

```
 @XmlRootElement
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class Rss {


     @XmlElement(name="channel")
     private Channel channel;


     public Channel getChannel() {
         return channel;
     }

     public void setChannel(Channel channel) {
         this.channel = channel;
     }

}
```

Another classs is

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="item")
public class Item {

     @XmlElement(name="g:id")
     private String id;


     public String getId() {
         return id;
     }
     public void setId(String id) {
         this.id = id;
     }
```

and the last item class is

```
public class Channel {


    private List<Item> itemList;

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    public List<Item> getItemList() {
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(List<Item> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }
}
```

this is what i am trying to do..please help what i am doing wrong as i all values extracted from the xml returns null.....

Comment: I have written a implementation but it provides null values for the extracted elements

Comment: You should show your implementation, so that someone can find your mistake.

Comment: sorry forgot to add that time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Rss` and `Channel` classes look OK to me.
The problem is in your `Item` class, especially in its elements with namespaces.

For modeling the `<g:id>` element you must not use `@XmlElement(name = "g:id")`.
Instead, you need to use `@XmlElement(name = "id", namespace = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")`.
This corresponds to the namespace definition `xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"` given in the XML file.

And by the way: You don't need `@XmlRootElement` on the `Item` class.
You need it only on the `Rss` class because `<rss>` is the XML root element.

The complete `Item` class would look like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlElement(name = "id", namespace = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "title", namespace = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")
    private String title;

    @XmlElement(name = "sport", namespace = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")
    private String sport;

    // public getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

You can find more background info here:

- [XML Namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) in general
- Oracle's [JAXB tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) for JAXB in general
- Javadoc for the [`@Xml...` annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html)
- for more just search the internet for *JAXB tutorial namespaces*

Comment: if you please post me the link to learn all these details .. then it will be very helpful to me...

Comment: @NaveenKushwaha added some links to my answer